# Whenever a failover occurs, either manually or automatically Immediately blocking problem occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration, sql-server-2019, failover

I have a table `log_table`, and I have two stored procedures: `insert_sp` for inserting log entries into the table, and `update_sp` for performing update operations.

I have a SQL Server failover cluster with two nodes. Whenever a failover occurs, either manually or automatically, the `log_table` gets blocked for 30-50 minutes.

Why this kind of problem occurs on the only failover except failover there is no any blocking on this table? How can I intervene to end the blocking? What can I do to prevent it from happening again?

Here is the `update_sp` stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[update_sp]
    @ID varchar(32),
    @Resp varchar(max),
    @RespDate datetime,
    @ServTime float = null
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[log_table]
    SET Resp = @Resp,
        RespDate = @RespDate,
        ServTime = DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,RequestDate,@RespDate)
    WHERE
        ID = @ID AND
        RecordTime > DATEADD(HOUR, -1 , GETDATE())  
END
```

Here is the `insert_sp` stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insert_sp]
    @ID varchar(32)
    @Resp varchar(max),
    @RequestDate datetime,
    @RespDate datetime,
    @ServTime float=null,
    @TranCode varchar(64) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[log_table] ([ID], [Resp], [RequestDate],[RespDate], [ServTime], TranCode)
     VALUES (@ID, @Resp, @RequestDate, @RespDate, @ServTime, @TranCode)
END
```

**Note:** I'm using SQL Server 2019 Enterprise (CU19)

I tried kill blocking SPID but every time occurs another id (no success).

I did a recompile for these 2 stored procedures (no success).

I tried to alter `update_sp` without altering operation, but it is already on blocking.

Comment: This isn't a question for [so]; you would be better off on [dba.se].

Comment: Add the `log_table` indexes to your question along with a link to the `sp_update` proc execution plan uploaded to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). It could be blocking occurs after the failover as a result of the cold cache.

Comment: Not related to the blocking _per se_, I have a lot of questions. ID is varchar(32) which is suspiciously number of bytes in a GUID minus the dashes. Having the db server calculate difference between RequestDate and RespDate - is the app server not capable of that? Updating log records post hoc. Storing what is presumably high velocity and volume data in a relational database at all.

Comment: When the blocking happens what is the wait type/ wait resource that it is waiting on?

Comment: waitresource="OBJECT: 82:1765581328:0 [COMPILE]"  @MartinSmith, But I recompiled this 2 store procedures. But I didn't succeded to fix the blocking problem

Comment: Is there a `blocking_session_id`? If so what is that session doing? Or if there is a chain of blocking what is at the head of the chain?